# Passing argument via executor.map

Tags: python

How can I send another argument via executor.map function?
See an example of code:

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from dask.dataframe import read_csv


def apply(row_of_small_df):
    # Here there is no access to big_df
    return


def main():
    small_df = read_csv('...')
    big_df = read_csv('...')
    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        results = executor.map(apply, small_df.iterrows())
        for result in results:
            pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another alternative is using [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

*Return a new partial object which when called will behave like func called with the positional arguments args and keyword arguments keywords. If more arguments are supplied to the call, they are appended to args. If additional keyword arguments are supplied, they extend and override keywords.*

```
from functools import partial

def apply(big_df, row_of_small_df):
    # requires big_df to be passed in
    return

def main():
    small_df = read_csv('...')
    big_df = read_csv('...')

    apply_with_big_df = partial(apply, big_df)

    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        results = executor.map(apply_with_big_df, small_df.iterrows())
        for result in results:
            pass
```

Answer (score 0):

use a lambda:

```py
#...
def apply(big_df, row_of_small_df):
    pass
#...
results = executor.map(lambda row_of_small: apply(big_df, row_of_small), small_df.iterrows())
#...
```

Comment: This code throw me an error, I'm not sure if the map function get a callable function as an argument here...

Answer (score 0):

Use the zip function like so

```
results = executor.map(apply, zip(big_df.iterrows(), small_df.iterrows()))
```

The function should now be

```
def apply(params):
    big, small = params
    # your code
```

Comment: This is not good for me, because I need big_df as full data frame in apply function